# Custom palette applied to dynamic theme

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to apply a theme dynamically. I do this by entering a HEX color on the site for primary and accent colors, and then I generate a map of colors and so on. The map looks like this once I'm done:

```
{
    "50": "8080ff",
    "100": "6666ff",
    "200": "4d4dff",
    "300": "3333ff",
    "400": "1a1aff",
    "500": "0000ff",
    "600": "0000e6",
    "700": "0000cc",
    "800": "0000b3",
    "900": "000099",
    "A100": "9999ff",
    "A200": "b3b3ff",
    "A400": "ccccff",
    "A700": "000080"
}
```

I then create a brand new palette using a theme provider (where `customPrimary` is my object above):

```
this.themeProvider.definePalette('customPrimary', customPrimary);
```

My `this.themeProvider` is my `$mdThemingProvider` sent from my `App.Config.ts` where I define the theme provider and so on. Basically `this.themeProvider = $mdThemingProvider`. Before you ask too many questions, go read this: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5502

I then generate a new theme and set the palettes and so on:

```
this.themeProvider.theme('whatever').primaryPalette('customPrimary').accentPalette('customAccent');

this.$mdTheming.generateTheme('whatever');

this.themeProvider.setDefaultTheme('whatever');
this.Theme = "whatever";
```

When I hit the save button on my page, the page theme changes to white and I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined

I cannot trace back where `colors` is defined. I certainly don't have a variable called `colors`. It seems like applying the palette to the theme is done wrong. Something doesn't seem right.

If I change out the palettes to something like `"blue"` it works fine. Setting my custom palettes just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately I can't provide an example, so please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: I've tried to replicate the problem but not succeeded. I've created a CodePen (http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qNzEWO?editors=1010) based on your code but don't get the error when clicking on the **Add Theme** button. Two things though: (1) I don't understand this part `this.Theme = "whatever";`, (2) I *do* get a similar error if I change **whatever** to **default** on line 34, but that doesn't really help, I suspect. Also, the theme doesn't appear to change when clicking on the button.

Comment: @camden_kid When I do `this.Theme = "whatever";` I change the overall theme of the app. I have a `md-theme="vm.Theme"` set on my body-tag, so whenever I change the theme (because I have a default theme and one an user sets) the theme changes to the new theme, instead of updating the default theme. Also, I can't seem to get yours to work. It doesn't change the theme when I press the button.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my last line the first line. Yes, it's not changing the theme. I just wanted to point out that I'm not getting your error. I'll look more into why the theme isn't changing...

Comment: As the last comment on that GitHub issue states, you have to define the palette in the config (I tried it and it does work). Defining the a palette dynamically doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @camden_kid That is so weird, since that other guy (the post I linked to) made it work? Since I'm parsing on the provider using $provide, it should work? :O

Comment: That guy says "the UI is not affected", which I take to mean the same problem we're having, i.e. the button colour does not change.

Comment: @camden_kid Ah that's really, really unfortunate... Man, I spent so much time writing a script to turn hex colors into palettes and so on (bear with me, this is my first project).. and now it doesn't work :( Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @MortenMoulder I have the same requirement. Have you found the solution? Can you tell me how did you covert hex colors into palette?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a partial solution - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qNzEWO?editors=1010)

Two things to note though

- This only seems to work for 'default' theme, not another name
- This doesn't seem to override any previous theme set up

After some exhaustive investigation I found that the customPrimary palette wasn't being setup in the same way as the default palettes, if it wasn't defined in the config. This is what I saw by looking at $mdThemingProvider in the console:

Blue

[image]

customPrimary

[image]

So I decided to create a custom palette called workingPrimary that mimicked the default palette data, i.e. using objects with contrast and value rather than a string. This seems to work. So the only trick now is to turn your hex values to contrast/value objects.

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.config(function ($mdThemingProvider, $provide) {  
  $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);
  $provide.value('themeProvider', $mdThemingProvider);
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdTheming, themeProvider) {
  var customPrimary = {
    "50": "8080ff",
    "100": "6666ff",
    "200": "4d4dff",
    "300": "3333ff",
    "400": "1a1aff",
    "500": "0000ff",
    "600": "0000e6",
    "700": "0000cc",
    "800": "0000b3",
    "900": "000099",
    "A100": "9999ff",
    "A200": "b3b3ff",
    "A400": "ccccff",
    "A700": "000080"
  }

  var workingPrimary = {
    "50": {contrast: [0, 0, 0, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "100": {contrast: [0, 0, 0, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "200": {contrast: [0, 0, 0, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "300": {contrast: [0, 0, 0, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "400": {contrast: [0, 0, 0, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "500": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [100, 100, 253]},
    "600": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "700": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "800": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "900": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "A100": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "A200": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "A400": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]},
    "A700": {contrast: [255, 255, 255, 0.87], value: [227, 242, 253]}
  };

  $scope.addTheme = function () {
    themeProvider.definePalette('customPrimary', customPrimary);

    themeProvider.definePalette('workingPrimary', workingPrimary);
    themeProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('workingPrimary', {"default": "500"});
    $mdTheming.generateTheme('default');
    $scope.theme = "default";

    console.log(themeProvider);
  }
});
```

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" md-theme="{{theme}}" md-theme-watch>
  <md-button ng-click="addTheme()">Add Theme</md-button>
  <br>
  <md-button class="md-primary">My Primary button</md-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that is strangely odd. I will definitely take a look at it tomorrow, when I get back to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @camden_kid Have you found the issue? Why palette customPrimary (with color-code) is not working?